# How do I spellcheck TeX files using vim-lexical, skipping some command arguments but not others?

Tags: filetype-tex, spell-checking, plugin-vimtex

I use the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin for TeX editing and [vim-lexical](https://github.com/reedes/vim-lexical) for spell-checking.

This works generally fine, but there are several commands vim-lexical tries to spellcheck. For example, in `\includepdf{pathToPdfFile}` it marks the path to the file as spelling mistake. How can I tell vim-lexical that it should ignore everything in some commands (such as `\includepdf`) but consider in some others (everything in `\bf` should be checked)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First: This is not related to `vim-lexical`. Syntax rules define where spell checking should be done, and so the current behaviour is defined by the internal syntax plugin for LaTeX.

The default syntax rule for tex command arguments allows spell checking. Some commands, e.g. `\include{...}`, are not spell checked. This is controlled by the `@Spell` and `@NoSpell` syntax clusters, see `:h spell-syntax` and `:h syn-spell`.

In order to add your own rules, you can create the file `.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`. An example rule that will match `\includepdf` and prevent spelling is:

```
syntax match texInputFile /\\includepdf\%(\[.\{-}\]\)\=\s*{.\{-}}/
      \ contains=texStatement,texInputCurlies,texInputFileOpt
```

Note that this rule makes the syntax matching of `\includepdf` correspond to `\include` and similar commands. To prevent spelling of other commands where such a correspondence does not make sense, you could also use:

```
syntax match texStatement '\\includepdf' nextgroup=texMyNoSpell
syntax region texMyNoSpell matchgroup=Delimiter start='{' end='}' contained
      \ contains=@NoSpell
```

---

Note: Please don't hesitate to [open issues with vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues) for things like this. vimtex provides some updates to the syntax rules on top of the internal syntax plugin, and the `\includepdf` command is a good example of commands I personally think should be matched.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it's worth mentioning that it's actually not the fault of `vimtex` neither. Most of the syntax definitions come with `vim` and are located at `/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/` (at least for ubuntu)

Comment: I think it is implied in the answer. I have already updated vimtex so that it fixes the spell checking for the `\includepdf` command.